# Add XmlDocument as child node to another XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have two XmlDocuments, one being the root and the other one containing the children. I want to combine them and save them into one document. Currently I have this:

```html
XmlDocument root = new XmlDocument();
root.LoadXml("<tables><table></table></tables>");

XmlDocument childItem = new XmlDocument();                  
childItem.LoadXml(string.Format(@"<item>
 <column columnName=""Article_text"">{0}</column>
 <column columnName=""Article_name"">{1}</column>
 </item>", atext, aname));

 root.AppendChild(childItem);
```

I want my new document's structure to be tables/table/item. However, the code above throws me an error:

> The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newNode = root.ImportNode(childItem.FirstChild, true);
root["tables"]["table"].AppendChild(newNode);
```

First import your *item* element to the *root* document. Expecting that *item* is your root node you can use [FirstChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.firstchild?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlNode_FirstChild) and [ImportNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_ImportNode_System_Xml_XmlNode_System_Boolean_) to get it:

```
 var newNode = root.ImportNode(childItem.FirstChild, true);
```

And append it to your *table* element:

```
root["tables"]["table"].AppendChild(newNode);
```